# How do I combine a dataset with worldmap

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I have a CSV File which i defined it as "Forest". It contains data about Deforestation from 1990 until 2015. I wanted to it to a world map, which shows every single country of the data set. unfortunately i cant see the countries on the map. Just the map itself.
Any ideas how i can show the countries with "Entity" "Annual net change...". My plan was also to create a slider to switch between the time

```
world_map = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')
chart = alt.Chart(world_map).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color=alt.Color('Annual net change in forest area:Q'),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip('properties.name:N', title='Country'),
        alt.Tooltip('properties.pop_est:Q', title='Population')
        ]
    ).properties(
    width=600,
    height=400
).project('naturalEarth1')\
.transform_lookup(lookup="Country", from_=alt.LookupData(Forest, 'Country', ['Country', 'Annual net change in forest area']))
chart.display()
```